# change font family in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm a beginner in java,
How can I change the font family of all texts (header, footer and body) in a `datatable`?

I found nothing about font family in datatables.jqueryui.css

Comment: Would u please comment about voting down?

Comment: same way you change any other css ... inspect the elements in browser dev tools to see what rules apply and adjust accordingly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to @charlietfl,

I use inspect element in the browser and found out the solution is adding `font-family` and `font-size` to `.dataTables_wrapper` in `dataTables.jqueryui.css`

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    *zoom: 1;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following implementation and works fine. 
By the way, in this example I am using **Bootstrap** and **Ajax** call.

```
<style>
  .table.dataTable  {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>
<table id="example" class="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font-family for everything inside the DataTable area (header, table, footer).

CSS

```
.dataTables_wrapper { font-family: "courier"}
```